# how to design or choose data structures based on different performance requirement for a C++ project

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, structure

I am learning C++ on my own and I would like to work a tiny project to improve my C++ skills.

I am implementing a program to have the capability of recording a number of different experiment tasks, each of which has a pre-defined time limit represented by integer numbers in time unit.

1. Different kinds of tasks can start at the same time or sequentially.
2. One kind of task can only run one at a time.
3. The tasks run normally with a duration of 24 hours at max.
4. The computer running the program have to suffer rebooting during the tasks within one day, for some reason. (so have to write data to disk)
5. One task can start and stop multiple times, so the time_elapsed is accumulated.

For example:

tasks,     time_limit(time unit),     time_elapsed(time unit).

t0,        500,                    0

t1,        1000,                   700

t2,        700,                    700

As you see, the project is just a timer. But I am not sure how to store the three parameters to my program; I have

1. string: task names;
2. integer: time limit, and
3. integer: time elapsed.

Basically there are **three variants** for the project asking for different ways (your suggestions) to store the above data:

1. total task numbers **are 10-100**; start-stop cycle AND query interval can be **minutes apart**, and no memory requirement;
2. total task numbers **are 10^100**; start-stop cycle AND query interval can be **millisecond scale**, and no memory requirement;
3. total task numbers **are 100!;** start-stop cycle AND query interval can be **milisecond scale**, and with as minimum mem as possible.

I have several solutions:

zeroth, I just have all the three variables in three primitive [] arrays, read / write files whenever updating it via array position-based indexing.

first, using vectors instead of arrays in the above case.

second, with unordered_map, set task-name as key and set time_limit, time_elapsed `pair<int, int>` as the value. whenever updating the record, input a task name(string) to update the corresponding integer value in the pair (C++ STL).

third, using a tuple `<string, int, int>` to store `<task_name, time_limit, time_elapsed>` respectively.

fourth, using C struct arrays, to have something like

```
struct {
         string task name;
         int time_limit
         int time_elapsed;};
```

Or any other types of data structure.

EDIT:

To query the data structure, current status at any time need to be transmitted to some other class objects of the program to trigger corresponding events(which is omitted in this post), thus a list of each unfinished (time_elapsed is less then time_limit) tasks' task_name, elapsed time and time left are read as input for the other class objects.

To think this way, it will help me learn a lot.

I would like to hear comments / suggests how to choose an efficient data structures based on different requirement listed above.

Thanks

Comment: One chooses a data structure not only to store data but also to support queries. Your question described what data you want to store. But it did not tell what kind of queries you want to run on top of the data. So there is no way I can tell you which structure is the most efficient.

Comment: Oh, you forgot to mention about B+ trees and Dynamic Hash Tables...

Comment: "how to choose an efficient data structure." how do you define efficiency? Seems like the performance of the app is not an issue - collection times being minutes apart. Memory foot-print? Coding style/cost of source maintenance?

Comment: @DonghuiZhang, thanks a lot for your comment, I've updated the question in the EDIT section to include the query format -- display a list of tasks and its time elapsed/left.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I made some update to the post based on your comment; briefly, the memory footprint is a consideration, and the collections can be 10 minutes apart, for example. Thanks a lot for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is that you have a collection of triples {task_name, time_limit, time_elapsed}. You frequently need to find a triple given its task_name, so as to update time_elapsed. You need to insert new triples. And when a task expires (time_elapsed >= time_limt) you should remove it from the collection (and possibly add to another collection), so as to be able to print the non-expired tasks.

You could do something like this:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Task {
  std::string task_name;
  size_t time_limit;
  size_t time_elapsed;
};

struct TaskLess {
  bool operator()(const Task& task1, const Task& task2) {
    return task1.task_name < task2.task_name;
  }
};

std::set<Task, TaskLess> tasks;
```

To find/update/insert/delete a task given its task_name is a logarithmic search. To print non-expired tasks you iterate through the set.

You could also consider further optimizations: (a) use an std::unordered_map instead of a set; (b) use an integer as a task key instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

btw, I've updated my post again, to ask for different time and space requirement. I'd really like to hear your answer.

Answer (score 0):

["Hitting a moving target" edit]

The answer below is offered for the scenario 1 - samples in the thousands or so.

Samples in the **10^100** or **100!** ranges - unless you have a [multiverse-sized computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content_.E2.80.93_number_of_atoms) better forget about it (number of atoms in the our observable universe is something around 10^80 - 10^81). Besides, I don't think you'd have time to accumulate such a high number of samples, given that the age of our universe is 13.8 billion years (which gives a magnitude order of 10^20 milliseconds count since the BigBang).

As of 2015, the entire CERN data size is a meagre [25 petabytes](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2960642/cloud-storage/cerns-data-stores-soar-to-530m-gigabytes.html) - that's less than 10^16.

---

Based on the scenario of usage (collection time at minutes apart, query for incomplete tasks), I'd go with your fourth solution, storing these structs in a `std:vector` - the number of entries to be stored/processed can't be that big so no need for special containers or a database (20 experiments running a month with 10 mins collection period will result in a bit over 3600 entries).

The query side, C++11 style, artificially blown up code (i.e. not the most compact form) to make evident what is happening:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> allSamples;

// assuming a code that fills allSamples up

// this is a lambda function, used as a predicate
auto unfinishedTest=[](const MyStruct& s) { 
  return s.time_elapsed < s.time_limit; 
}

auto unfinishedIterator=std::find_if(
  allSamples.begin(), allSamples.end(), // range of lookup
  unfinishedTest // filtering predicate
);

// now you have an iterator which only gives you unfinished tests
while(unfinishedIterator != allSamples.end()) {
  const MySample& unfinishedJobAtHand = *unfinishedIterator;
  // do what you please 
}
```

References:

- [std:: containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) with [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in particular
- [find_if specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)
- [lamda functions syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, especially for the links!

btw, I've updated my post again, to ask for different time and space requirement. I'd really like to hear your answer.

Comment: @kaka0512 - " to ask for different time and space requirement" whoaaa! Don't do that, please. It invalidates the answers already provided - "hitting a moving target" and all that. Better open a new question referencing the old one.

Comment: @kaka0512 - updated my answer and discounted your second and third use cases. I mean ... you really want to consider those cases?